# Passing File manually instead of stdin value_t read_sexpr(FILE *f) in c

Tags: objective-c, file, stdin, femtolisp

I am using c file which takes input from console

```
value_t read_sexpr(FILE *f) // This is a Function 
 read_sexpr(stdin) // Thats how it is calling from main
```

I want to pass string instead of taking input from console . Can it be done ?

Comment: In c++ there is `std:istringstream`.

Comment: yup i tried , I ,ve not good skills in c so i failed :/

Comment: What, you want to pass a string to your program as a command line parameter?

Comment: What platform are you programming on?

Comment: Yes because i ,m gonna use it in IOS and stdin is not gonna work there so i want to pass string

Comment: IOS Objective-C @FUZxxl

Comment: @MubasherKhan If you are programming in objective C, tag as [tag:objective-c], not as [tag:c]!

Comment: Removed the C tag. Feel free to add the correct tag yourself.

Comment: There's a promising-looking implementation of `fmemopen` for OS X / iOS [here](https://github.com/NimbusKit/MemoryMapping) (Apache 2.0 license).

Comment: Listen i was using pure C in Objective C so I put the C flag .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `fmemopen()` to open a `FILE` backed by a string:

```
#include <stdio.h>

const char mystring[] = "test";
FILE *testfile = fmemopen(mystring, sizeof mystring, "r");
```

Note that `fmemopen` is not a standard C function. It is standard POSIX though.

Don't forget to close the file afterwards. Read the [manual page](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fmemopen.html) for more details.

Comment: Bundle of Thanks . It really helped :)